# i can't print names with only uppercase

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops, while-loop

i just wanna to know how can i print the names with **first capital letter** in the list and **ignore** who **starts with lowercase** in **python** with **while Loop**

```
# Input
friends = ["Mohamed", "Shady", "ahmed", "eman", "Sherif"]

# Needed Output
"Mohamed"
"Shady"
"Sherif"
"Friends Printed And Ignored Names Count Is 2"
```

Comment: What is supposed to be the purpose of the `while` loop? You can just use a regular for loop for this.

Comment: just the challenge need me to use the While loop

Answer (score 2):

You can use [ord](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord) builtin function to determine if the character is uppercase or lowercase. You can also use the `isupper` method. Here is the sample code:

```
print([f for f in friends if f[0].isupper()])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to only those values have the first uppercase letter.

```
friends = ["Mohamed", "Shady", "ahmed", "eman", "Sherif"]


for a in friends:
    if a[0].isupper():
        print(a)
```

Output

```
Mohamed
Shady
Sherif
```

---

You can try this too

```
friends = ["Mohamed", "Shady", "ahmed", "eman", "Sherif"]

uppercase = list(filter(lambda e: e[0].istitle(),friends) )
lowercase = list(filter(lambda e: e[0].islower(),friends))


print(uppercase)
print(lowercase)
```

OUTPUT

```
['Mohamed', 'Shady', 'Sherif']
['ahmed', 'eman']
```

---

If you want only the titleCase *"(use for a name.)"* string You can use `str.istitle()`.

```
friends = ["Mohamed", "Shady", "ahmed", "eman", "Sherif"]


for a in friends:
    if a.istitle():
        print(a)
```

OUtput

```
Mohamed
Shady
Sherif
```

Answer (score 0):

The ***isupper()*** function can be used for this.

Ref: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/isupper-islower-lower-upper-python-applications/

```
friends = ["Mohamed", "Shady", "ahmed", "eman", "Sherif"]

# To print the words which start with Uppercase.
for val in friends:
    if val[0].isupper():
        print(val)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the most elegant solution, but works as long as you are ignoring typos in names like "MOhamed":

```
# Input
friends = ["Mohamed", "Shady", "ahmed", "eman", "Sherif"]

uppercase = []
lowercase = []

for friend in friends:
    if friend[0].isupper() == True:
        uppercase.append(friend)
    else: 
        lowercase.append(friend)

for name in uppercase: 
    print(name)
    
print("Ingnored names: {}".format(len(lowercase)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `for` loop and compare the element of list to `str.capitalize()` with `while` then print the elements.

You also need `ignored` counter to count element that not capitalize to print in the last statement:

```
friends = ["Mohamed", "Shady", "ahmed", "eman", "Sherif", "BATMAN", 'deJavu']

ignored = 0

for friend in friends:
    while friend != friend.capitalize():
        ignored += 1
        break
    else:
        print(friend)

print(f"Friends Printed And Ignored Names Count Is {ignored}")

# Mohamed
# Shady
# Sherif
# Friends Printed And Ignored Names Count Is 4
```